# How to Implement a Trig Identity Proving Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, symbolic-math

How could I implement a program that takes in the two sides of a trig equation (could be generalized to anything but for now I'll leave it at just trig identities) and the program will output the steps to transform one side into another (or transform them both) to show that they are in fact equal. The program will assume that they are equal in the first place. I am quite stumped as to how I might implement an algorithm to do this. My first thought was something to do with graphs, but I couldn't think of anything beyond this. From there, I thought that I should first parse both sides of the equation into trees. For example `(cot x * sin) / (sin x + cos x)` would look like this:

```
     division
     /    \
    *      +
  /  \    / \
cot sin sin cos
```

After this, I had two similar ideas, both of which have problems. The first idea was to pick the side with the least number of leaves and try to manipulate it into the other side by using equivalencies that would be represented by "tree regexs." Examples of these "tree regexs" would be `csc = 1 / sin` or `cot = cos / sin` (in tree form of course), etc. My second idea would be to pick the side with more leaves and try to find some expression that when multiplied by that expression would equal the other side. Using reciprocals this wouldn't be too bad, however, I would then have to prove that the thing I multiplied by equals 1. Again I am back to this "tree regex" thing.

The major flaw with both of these is in what order/how could I apply these substitutions. Will it just have to be a big mess of if statements or is there a more elegant solution? Is there actually a graph-based solution that I'm not seeing. **What (if any) might be a good algorithm to prove trig identities.**

To be clear I am not talking about the "solve for x" type problem such as `tan(x)sin(x) = 5`, find all values of x but rather prove that `sqrt((1 + sin x) / (1 - sin x)) = sec x + tan x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look out for texts on computer algebra (which I haven't), I'm sure you'll find clever ideas there.

My approach would be a graph-based search, as I doubt that a linear application of transformations will reliably lead to a solution.

Express the whole equation as an expression-tree the way you already started, but including an "equals" node above.

For the search-graph view, take one expression-tree as one search-state. The search-target is a decidable expression-tree like 1=1 or 1=0. When searching (expanding a search-state), create the child states by applying equivalence transformations on your expression (regex-like sounds quite plausible to me). Define an evaluation function that counts the overall complexity of an expression (e.g. number of nodes in the expression-tree). Do a directed search minimizing the evaluation function (expanding the lowest-complexity expression first), thus simplifying the expression until you reach a decidable form.

Depending on the expressions, it's quite possible that an unrestricted search never terminates. I don't know how you'd handle that, maybe by limiting the allowed complexity of expressions to some multiple of the original one. That would reduce the risk of running indefinitely, but leave you with undecided cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple algorithm for deciding trigonometric identities that can be brought into the form `polynomial(sin x, cos x) = 0` :

1. Get rid of `tan x`, `cot x`, `sec x`, ..., `sin 2x`, ... by the obvious substitutions (`tan x -> (sin x)/(cos x)`, ..., `sin 2x -> 2 (sin x) (cos x)`, ...)
2. Transform identity to polynomial by squaring (isolated) roots (getting rid of multiple roots in an identity can be tricky, though), multiplying with denominators and bringing all expanded terms to one side
3. Replace all terms `cos^2 x` in the polynomial (`cos^3 x = (cos^2 x)(cos x)`, `cos^4 x = (cos^2 x)(cos^2 x)`, ...) by `1 - sin^2 x` and expand the polynomial.
4. Finally a polynomial without `cos^2 x` is computed. If it is identical to 0 the identity is proven, otherwise the identity does not hold.

Your example `sqrt((1 + sin x)/(1 - sin x)) = sec x + tan x`:

1. Using the substitutions `sec x -> 1/(cos x)` and `tan x -> (sin x)/(cos x)` we get

`sqrt((1 + sin x)/(1 - sin x)) = 1/(cos x) + (sin x)/(cos x)`.

For brevity let us write `s` instead of `sin x` and `c` instead of `cos x`, which gives us:

`sqrt((1 + s)/(1 - s)) = 1/c + s/c`

2. Squaring the equation and multiplying both sides with `(1 - s)c^2` we get

`(1 + s)c^2 = (1 + s)^2(1 - s)`.

Expanding the parenthesis and bringing everthing to one side we get

`c^2 - sc^2 + s^3 + s^2 - s - 1 = 0`

3. Substituting `c^2 = 1 - s^2` into the polynomial we get

`(1 - s^2) - s(1 - s^2) + s^3 + s^2 - s - 1` which expands to `0`.

4. Hence the identity is proven.

Comment: Ok this seems like a clever and good solution. However, in the example you square both sides then multiply both sides by (1-s)c^2. Will squaring when necessary then multiplying by (potentially 2) denominators always work?

Comment: In step 2 we go for a polynomial. Clearing denominators and bringing all terms to one side is straight forward. Getting rid of several roots can be tricky or even impossible by just squaring. If you have two roots and other terms, you bring the two roots to one side, the rest to the other side. After squaring both sides you will have still one root, which must be isolated before squaring both sides again. Three roots and no other terms works the same way. For three roots and more terms consecutive squaring and isolating may never terminate. But how many identities of this form do you know?